# AG-Grid React: Allow pagination panel to set the page size via a dropdown & Allow pagination panel to set the current page via a textbox

Tags: ag-grid-react

Currently managed the customized pagination but facing an issue, if the current page is not the first page and trying to change page size from default 50 to 100 then it set startRow to 0 & endRow to 100, instead of this result I want startRow to 100 & endRow to 200. So Is it possible to provide any expected date for AG-6381 & AG-6377 [pipeline: https://www.ag-grid.com/pipeline/]release date? As it will solve my problem & no need to implement the customized pagination.

While change the page size from pagination panel dropdown, manage the code: ref?.current?.api?.paginationSetPageSize(pageSize);.

It calls the getRows() as I am using server-side model, but startRow & endRow behaviour is not as per my exepectation.

Expectation: if page is second & changing pagesize then while getRows() calls my startRows should be 100 & endRows should be 200.